# Spring-cloud-contracts stub latest version resolving

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

Lets assume that we have a project Foo which defines its contract. I've developed it on branch X and published stub jar to maven snapshots repository with version 0.0.1-X-SNAPSHOT.

After all I released it with version 0.0.1 and published to maven released repository.

Then I wanted use it on my other consumer service so I configured stubrunner in given way:

```
stubrunner:
  repository-root: http://myreleased.repo,http://mysnapshot.repo
  work-offline: false
```

The problem is that in that case the latest resolved version is 0.0.1-X-SNAPSHOT not 0.0.1 as I expected to be as I want released to take precedence over snapshot.

Any suggestion how to fix that? The simplest solution of course is to remove snapshot repository from list or repository-root but are there any other?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that in that case the latest resolved version is 0.0.1-X-SNAPSHOT not 0.0.1 as I expected to be as I want released to take precedence over snapshot.

I think it takes timestamp into account. AFAIR you could change the `+` in the version to `latest.release`. And if that doesn't work then you'd have to run the test twice with different repo roots.